# jquery .val() outputs default input field value from html not user entered one

Tags: jquery, validation

I've a problem... I'm trying to grab all input field data for validation, but .val() returns default value from html rather than what user inputed. Maybe it is because I've this script inside domready? I cannot figure it out... and to make things better on jsfiddle it works! :S

```
$(document).ready(function() {


        //Login Ajax
        $("#loginform").submit(function(){
            var url = $(this).attr("action");

            //Get input variables
            var user_name = $("input[name=user_name]");
            var user_password = $("input[name=user_password]");

                        //border control
                        if (user_name.val() == "username" && user_password.val() == "password") {
                            user_name.addClass("error");
                            user_password.addClass("error");
                            return false;
                        } else {
                            user_name.removeClass("error");
                            user_password.removeClass("error");
                        }

                            if (user_name.val() == "username") {
                                user_name.addClass("error");
                                return false;
                            } else {
                                user_name.removeClass("error");
                            }

                        if (user_password.val() == "password") {
                            user_password.addClass("error");
                            return false;
                        } else {
                            user_password.removeClass("error");
                        }

            return false;
        });


        //Registration Ajax
        $("#regsitrationform").submit(function(){
            var url = $(this).attr("action");


            return false;
        });


});
```

Comment: Can you provide a fiddle link? Also you can do one thing . Put your default value in placeholder
`<input type="text" name="test" value="" placeholder="Default Value" />`

Comment: Can you post the HTML of the page as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am only guessing but maybe you are in the wrong context.

If there are multiple inputs with the same name on your page you have to tell jQuery which one should be used.

In your submit callback `this`refers to the form element. So your could might look like this:

```
var user_name = $("input[name=user_name]", this);
var user_password = $("input[name=user_password]", this);
```

Comment: Wild guess but you are totally right! Have two elements... for login and registration with same name... thanks!!!!!

Comment: This just saved me HOURS of time!